# CTE Query. The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this sql query now facing the below error

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted
> before statement completion.

```
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT H.Person,
           H.AssignedTo,
           H.Person AS NextPerson,
           H.AssignedTo AS NextAssignedTo,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),CONCAT('|',H.AssignedTo,'|')) AS ExpectedResult,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.tblHierarchy H
    UNION ALL      
    SELECT r.Person,
           r.AssignedTo,
           H.Person AS NextPerson,
           H.AssignedTo AS NextAssignedTo,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),CONCAT(r.Expectedresult,H.AssignedTo,'|')),
           Level + 1
    FROM dbo.tblHierarchy H
         JOIN rCTE r ON r.NextAssignedTo = H.Person),
RNs AS(
    SELECT r.Person,
           r.AssignedTo,
           r.ExpectedResult,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.Person ORDER BY r.level DESC) AS RN
    FROM rCTE r)
SELECT RN.Person,
       RN.AssignedTo,
       RN.ExpectedResult
FROM RNs RN
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY RN.Person;
```

Not sure where to add **option (maxrecursion 0)** in the above query to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused default recursion was 100, but your query might more than that, you can try to add this hint on the end of a query

> The server-wide default is 100. When 0 is specified, no limit is applied. Only one [MAXRECURSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) value can be specified per statement. For more information

I would set a number for that instead of `0` if you have expected the most recursive deep.

```
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT H.Person,
           H.AssignedTo,
           H.Person AS NextPerson,
           H.AssignedTo AS NextAssignedTo,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),CONCAT('|',H.AssignedTo,'|')) AS ExpectedResult,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.tblHierarchy H
    UNION ALL      
    SELECT r.Person,
           r.AssignedTo,
           H.Person AS NextPerson,
           H.AssignedTo AS NextAssignedTo,
           CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),CONCAT(r.Expectedresult,H.AssignedTo,'|')),
           Level + 1
    FROM dbo.tblHierarchy H
         JOIN rCTE r ON r.NextAssignedTo = H.Person),
RNs AS(
    SELECT r.Person,
           r.AssignedTo,
           r.ExpectedResult,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.Person ORDER BY r.level DESC) AS RN
    FROM rCTE r)
SELECT RN.Person,
       RN.AssignedTo,
       RN.ExpectedResult
FROM RNs RN
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY RN.Person
option (maxrecursion 0);
```